# Get the latest value per timeserie

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

How to query the latest value per timeserie in MetricsQL or PromQL?

For example, query `metric_name` returns two timeseries for `metric_name{job="foo"}` and `metric_name{job="bar"}` for a long range:

```
{"metric":{"__name__":"metric_name","job":"foo"},"values":[.................. <long list>],
{"metric":{"__name__":"metric_name","job":"bar"},"values":[.................. <long list>]
```

Is there a way to get the latest value for each label? So that response would contain only two timestamps -- one for job="foo", and another for job="bar":

```
{"metric":{"__name__":"metric_name","job":"foo"},"values":[1510000000,123],
{"metric":{"__name__":"metric_name","job":"bar"},"values":[1610000000,321]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use `last_over_time`?

```
last_over_time(m[d]) - returns the last value for m on the time range d.
```

See more details about MetricsQL here - https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL

You might want to use `/api/v1/query` endpoint to get an instant query result.

Comment: `/api/v1/query` will return only one result, as it requires `time=****` param, even if implicitly

Comment: last_over_time() may not return a single value either, or, more correctly, it respects `step` query parameter. I tried `last_over_time(vm_app_version[365d])` with different `step` values. Seems like the problem has to deal more with `step` param and not query, but I'm not sure what to do with it.