# How to get the last value received in Prometheus/VictoriaMetrics with promQL/metricsQL

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I want to get the last value ingested by Prometheus/VictoriaMetrics for a specific time series. How can I query for that?

The value could have been ingested 5mins ago or 1sec ago.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711837/get-the-latest-value-per-timeserie/65726014

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the latest value per timeserie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711837/get-the-latest-value-per-timeserie)